# Chaining higher order mapping operators - how does it work under the hood?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I need to reset the data in my database which involves the actions -

1. fetch all data
2. delete all data
3. create new data

in sequence, and I have the following three methods in my service -

```js
getAllData(): Observable<IUser[]> {
    //
}

clearAllData(users: IUser[]): Observable<boolean> {
    //
}

generateNewData(cleared: boolean): Observable<IUser[]> {
    //
}
```

In my component, I used them like below -

```js
resetData(): void {
    this.service.getAllData()
        .pipe(
            concatMap(p => this.service.clearAllData(p)
                .pipe(
                    concatMap(p => this.service.generateNewData(p))
                ))
        )
        .subscribe(
            p => {
                this.dataSource = p;
            },
            e => {
                console.log('Error: ', e)
            }
        );
}
```

It works. It also works if I used them like -

```js
resetData(): void {
    this.service.getAllData()
        .pipe(
            concatMap(p => this.service.clearAllData(p)),
            concatMap(p => this.service.generateNewData(p))
        )
        .subscribe(
            p => {
                this.dataSource = p;
            },
            e => {
                console.log('Error: ', e)
            }
        );
}
```

I'm just trying to understand the difference between how this two approaches work behind the scene.

As far as I know, higher order mapping operators subscribes to their outer observable. Therefore, in the first approach -

- the first `concatMap()` subscribes to the observable returned by the `service.getAllData()` method, and
- the second `concatMap()` subscribes to the observable returned by the `service.clearAllData()` method

(Please correct me if I'm wrong here).

But in the second approach, shouldn't both `concatMap()` subscribe to the observable returned by the `service.getAllData()` method?

How are the both approach producing the same result then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Higher order mapping operators automatically subscribe to and unsubscribe from their *inner* Observable.

So in both cases, they subscribe to the Observable returned by the service method called within the operator's arrow function.

Both of these options behave the same because in both cases, concatMap will wait to complete it's operation and emit before moving on to it's pipeable operators OR it's next sibling operator.

Make sense?

Comment: I was following your Pluralsight course - `RxJS in Angular: Reactive Development` and looks like I got the wrong idea that the higher order mapping operator causes to subscribe to the _outer_ observable. Thanks for your response. For a general best practice, which of the two approaches should I follow?

Comment: :-)  From a code readability standpoint, the second may be a bit easier to read without the additional indented pipe.

Comment: "_before moving on to it's pipeable operators OR it's next sibling operator_" - that `OR` made it all clear why both approaches work the same. Thanks again.